# How do I write a JPA criteria query to find an object in a date range and include the endpoints of that date range?

Tags: hibernate, date, jpa, range, jpa-2.1

I’m using JPA 2.1 with Hibenrate 5.1.0.Final.  How do I write a JPA CriteriaBuilder query in which I’m querying for objects in a date range and I want to include the endpoints of the date range in my query?  I’m noticing that the following code

```
final java.util.Date searchDate = objectDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
    final ParameterExpression<Date> d = builder.parameter(Date.class);
    query.where(
            …
            builder.between(d, objectRoot.<Date>get(MyObject_.objectDate), objectRoot.<Date>get(MyObject_.objectEndDate)));
```

This query will not return any results if the criteria falls exactly on one of the endpoints.

Comment: lessThanOrEqualTo, greaterThanOrEqualTo? Other than that you have to post the SQL generated, because debugging something like this without posting SQL is a bit pointless

Comment: Come on, Neil, you don't need to see SQL to understand the question.  "between" doesn't include the endpoints, this is in their documentation.  I want to include the endpoints.  It sounds like lessThanOrEqualTo, greaterThanOrEqualTo is the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Problems concerning date fields are almost always because of the time component.  Since searchDate is the time at the start of date (DD-MON-YY 12:00am), when comparing with the low end of the BETWEEN might not match because of difference in time.